Acumatica - PXRedirectException interceptor
Acumatica provides the redirection to a SO/PO from multiple places, we have some customization where the customization has its own SO/PO page, so all redirection are suppose to land to new page instead of old.
this can be done by updating all redirect code on all the places, that is difficult to identify, Is there a common place where redirection can be checked for the given SO/PO and then redirect to new page (Something like interceptor), this will make the code more robust.

I think, what you need is to override the default navigation declared with a PXPrimaryGraphAttribute which is usually declared on a DAC class:
[PXPrimaryGraph(typeof(MyGraph))]
public class MyDac : IBqlTable
{}

In that case, I suggest you to take a look at this post:
https://community.acumatica.com/develop-customizations-288/how-to-override-the-default-navigation-for-dac-24628
In short, you can add to a DAC extension PXPrimaryGraphAttribute directing to a new graph. Or you can add PXPrimaryGraphAttribute to a graph/graph extension and list DACs that should be redirected to the screen using this graph.
